# rock scissor paper program

Tags: python

Here are code for writing rock scissors paper game in python.
If I run the code, it works but, when it becomes tie, it outputs like this.
Is there anyway I can eliminate print(round) when I get result of tie?
I want to look it like as shown at bottom of example

*********************ROUND #1*********************

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? p
Tie!

*********************ROUND #1*********************

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? s
Computer threws rock, you lose!

Your Score:  0
Computer Score:  1

********************* ROUND #3 *********************

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? s
 Tie!

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? p
 Tie!

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? r
 Computer threw scissors, you win!

Your score: 2
Computer’s score: 1

```
# A Python program for the Rock, Paper, Scissors game. 
import random

def rock_paper_scissors():
''' Write your code for playing Rock Paper Scissors here. '''
user = 0
computer = 0
rounds = 1   

print()
score = (int(input('How many points does it take to win? ')))
print()

while (computer < score and user < score):
    RPS = random.randint(0,2)
    if (RPS == 0):
        RPS = 'rock'
    elif (RPS == 1):
        RPS = 'paper'
    elif(RPS == 2):
        RPS = 'scissors'


    print('*'*21 + 'ROUND #'+str(rounds) + '*'*21)
    print()
    player = (input('Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? '))


    if  RPS == 'rock' and player == 'r':
        print('Tie!')

    elif RPS == 'rock' and player == 's':
        print('Computer threws rock, you lose!')
        computer+=1
        rounds += 1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)
    elif RPS == 'rock' and player == 'p':
        print('Computer threw rock, you win!')
        user+=1
        rounds +=1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)            
    if  RPS == 'paper' and player == 'p':
        print('Tie!')
    elif RPS == 'paper' and player == 'r':
        print('Computer threw paper, you lose!')
        computer +=1
        rounds += 1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)            
    elif RPS == 'paper' and player == 's':
        print('Computer threw paper, you win!')
        user +=1
        rounds +=1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)        
    if RPS == 'scissors' and player == 's':
        print('Tie!')
    elif RPS == 'scissors'and player == 'p':
        print('Computer threw scissors, you lose!')
        computer +=1
        rounds+=1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)            
    elif RPS == 'scissors' and player == 'r':
        print('Computer threw scissors, you win!')
        user +=1
        rounds+=1
        print()
        print('Your Score: ',user)
        print('Computer Score: ',computer)            
    print()

if user> computer:
    print('*'*21 + 'GAME OVER' + '*'*21)
    print('You win!')
else:
    print('*'*21 + 'GAME OVER' + '*'*21)
    print('Computer win!')

print()        

def main(): 
print('ROCK PAPER SCISSORS in Python')
print()
print('Rules: 1) Rock wins over Scissors.')
print('       2) Scissors wins over Paper.')
print('       3) Paper wins over Rock.')

rock_paper_scissors()

main()
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a boolean `was_tied`, setting it to equal `False` at the start of the program, and setting it to either `True` or `False` at the end of each possible outcome. Then you can put your print-round code inside of an `if not was_tied` statement.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you have a number of areas that could simplify this code, but for a quick solution, at this line:

```
print('*'*21 + 'ROUND #'+str(rounds) + '*'*21)
print()
```

change it to:

```
if not previous_round_was_tie:
    print('*'*21 + 'ROUND #'+str(rounds) + '*'*21)
    print()
```

And in all the cases where your tie scenario is true, add a line `previous_round_was_tie = True`. You'll also have to create the boolean and set it to `False` outside of your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks!
it works on tie round, but other rounds such as win and lost section did not ouput a string(round)

Comment: *********************ROUND #1*********************

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? p
Tie!

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors? p
Computer threw scissors, you lose!

Your Score:  0
Computer Score:  1

Pick your throw: [r]ock, [p]aper, or [s]cissors?

Comment: @KyungwonSuh If this solution worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!